# 1 parameter, 2 given in ... after migrating from localhost

Tags: php, file-upload, data-migration

I've moved my website live and I'm getting error.

`1 parameter, 2 given in ... on line 57`

The line is exactly:

`file_put_contents( $files['owg'], json_encode( $data, true ) );`

The whole thing is:

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
 if ( !empty( $_POST['owg'] ) ) {
    $data['owg'] = nl2br( trim( $_POST['owg'] ) );
    file_put_contents( $files['owg'], json_encode( $data, true ) );
    unset( $data );
  }
}
```

Chmods are 777 on files and folders. Why is this error not appearing at localhost?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with `json_encode( $data, true )` ? in the php docs, the bitmask uses the following constants: http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php, so you should use it this way: `json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS)` with the options you want.

Comment: Thanks! This is it! I thought that json_encode's 2nd parameter will be like in opposite function json_decode. I did not checked it before. But why it is working on localhost?

Comment: what kind of operating system do you use? maybe it's a different implementation, and uses true as 0xFFFF or so, and in production its a boolean.

Comment: Ubuntu localhost LAMP, probably the same at www but didn't checked yet for PHP ver itp but seems low I can't use new array syntax [] on the www server